# WebRTC: Firefox ICE candidates fail

Tags: javascript, firefox, webrtc

Locally works calling from:

```
Chrome / Opera --> To --> Chrome/Opera
Chrome / Opera --> To --> Firefox
Firefox --> To --> Firefox
Firefox --> To --> Chrome / Opera
and vice versa
```

On the internet (accross the city) works calling from:

```
Chrome / Opera --> To --> Chrome/Opera
But fails all calls made to and from Firefox
```

SDPs: (Ips have been masked)

Local SDP

```
v=0
o=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-45.0.2 339225128162318377 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=sendrecv
a=fingerprint:sha-256 5D:6E:45:CC:22:3E:B1:B8:8D:0F:F2:79:28:47:23:DE:B5:8A:B7:02:1B:11:FB:A3:9B:0C:4D:DF:53:FC:AA:94
a=ice-options:trickle
a=msid-semantic:WMS *
m=audio 60427 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 109
c=IN IP4 192.168.178.13
a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2122187007 192.168.178.13 60427 typ host
a=candidate:2 1 UDP 2122252543 IPV 60428 typ host
a=sendrecv
a=end-of-candidates
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=ice-pwd:ef73d2784dbf77e0db1dbe839987f114
a=ice-ufrag:50149691
a=mid:sdparta_0
a=msid:{10df8e89-e559-409f-80b8-4b6036ea4eb6} {c89496a1-7d44-422a-9050-27aa9f2f3f97}
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2
a=setup:active
a=ssrc:3974826805 cname:{44169fc1-4761-4c31-a82d-0398fcd5bce7}
```

Remote SDP

```
v=0
o=mozilla...THIS_IS_SDPARTA-45.0.2 339225128162318377 0 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=sendrecv
a=fingerprint:sha-256 5D:6E:45:CC:22:3E:B1:B8:8D:0F:F2:79:28:47:23:DE:B5:8A:B7:02:1B:11:FB:A3:9B:0C:4D:DF:53:FC:AA:94
a=ice-options:trickle
a=msid-semantic:WMS *
m=audio 60427 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 109
c=IN IP4 192.168.178.13
a=candidate:0 1 UDP 2122187007 192.168.178.13 60427 typ host
a=candidate:2 1 UDP 2122252543 IPV 60428 typ host
a=sendrecv
a=end-of-candidates
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=ice-pwd:ef73d2784dbf77e0db1dbe839987f114
a=ice-ufrag:50149691
a=mid:sdparta_0
a=msid:{10df8e89-e559-409f-80b8-4b6036ea4eb6} {c89496a1-7d44-422a-9050-27aa9f2f3f97}
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:109 opus/48000/2
a=setup:active
a=ssrc:3974826805 cname:{44169fc1-4761-4c31-a82d-0398fcd5bce7}
```

These are the logs from inside Firefox on the receiving end (ips / urls have been changed):

```
(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com)): No STUN servers specified
(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com)): No TURN servers specified
(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com)): peer (PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com):default) no streams with non-empty check lists
(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com)): peer (PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com):default) no streams with pre-answer requests
(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com)): peer (PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com):default) no checks to start
(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com):default)/CAND-PAIR(dujC): setting pair to state FROZEN: dujC|IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP|IP6:[2222:1c03:2d05:7900:21e:33ff:fee1:cccc]:55401/UDP(host(IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP)|candidate:0 1 UDP 2122252543 2222:1c03:2d05:7900:21e:33ff:fee1:cccc 55401 typ host)
(ice/INFO) ICE(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com))/CAND-PAIR(dujC): Pairing candidate IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP (7e7f00ff):IP6:[2222:1c03:2d05:7900:21e:33ff:fee1:cccc]:55401/UDP (7e7f00ff) priority=9115005270282338815 (7e7f00fffcfe01ff)
(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com):default)/ICE-STREAM(1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com) aLevel=0): Starting check timer for stream.
(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com):default)/CAND-PAIR(dujC): setting pair to state WAITING: dujC|IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP|IP6:[2222:1c03:2d05:7900:21e:33ff:fee1:cccc]:55401/UDP(host(IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP)|candidate:0 1 UDP 2122252543 2222:1c03:2d05:7900:21e:33ff:fee1:cccc 55401 typ host)
(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com):default)/CAND-PAIR(dujC): setting pair to state IN_PROGRESS: dujC|IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP|IP6:[2222:1c03:2d05:7900:21e:33ff:fee1:cccc]:55401/UDP(host(IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP)|candidate:0 1 UDP 2122252543 2222:1c03:2d05:7900:21e:33ff:fee1:cccc 55401 typ host)
(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com)): peer (PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com):default) is now checking
(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com):default)/CAND-PAIR(Yh2V): setting pair to state FROZEN: Yh2V|IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP|IP6:[1111:1c03:2d05:7900:e5d6:372:496b:bbbb]:55402/UDP(host(IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP)|candidate:2 1 UDP 2122121471 1111:1c03:2d05:7900:e5d6:372:496b:bbbb 55402 typ host)
(ice/INFO) ICE(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com))/CAND-PAIR(Yh2V): Pairing candidate IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP (7e7f00ff):IP6:[1111:1c03:2d05:7900:e5d6:372:496b:bbbb]:55402/UDP (7e7d00ff) priority=9114442320328917502 (7e7d00fffcfe01fe)
(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com):default)/CAND-PAIR(P3yk): setting pair to state FROZEN: P3yk|IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP|IP6:[2001:1c03:2d05:7900:9d1c:c035:5b10:326]:55403/UDP(host(IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP)|candidate:4 1 UDP 2122187007 2001:1c03:2d05:7900:9d1c:c035:5b10:326 55403 typ host)
(ice/INFO) ICE(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com))/CAND-PAIR(P3yk): Pairing candidate IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP (7e7f00ff):IP6:[2001:1c03:2d05:7900:9d1c:c035:5b10:326]:55403/UDP (7e7e00ff) priority=9114723795305628158 (7e7e00fffcfe01fe)
(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com):default)/CAND-PAIR(3Smw): setting pair to state FROZEN: 3Smw|IP4:192.168.178.13:60427/UDP|IP4:192.168.178.13:55404/UDP(host(IP4:192.168.178.13:60427/UDP)|candidate:6 1 UDP 2122055935 192.168.178.13 55404 typ host)
(ice/INFO) ICE(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com))/CAND-PAIR(3Smw): Pairing candidate IP4:192.168.178.13:60427/UDP (7e7e00ff):IP4:192.168.178.13:55404/UDP (7e7c00ff) priority=9114160845352075774 (7e7c00fffcfc01fe)
(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com)): peer (PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com):default) specified too many components
(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com)): peer (PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com):default) specified too many components
(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com)): peer (PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com):default) specified too many components
(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com)): peer (PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com):default) specified too many components
(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com)): failed to resolve candidate srflx(IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP|stun3.l.google.com:19305).
(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com):default)/CAND-PAIR(P3yk): setting pair to state WAITING: P3yk|IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP|IP6:[2001:1c03:2d05:7900:9d1c:c035:5b10:326]:55403/UDP(host(IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP)|candidate:4 1 UDP 2122187007 2001:1c03:2d05:7900:9d1c:c035:5b10:326 55403 typ host)
(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com):default)/CAND-PAIR(P3yk): setting pair to state IN_PROGRESS: P3yk|IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP|IP6:[2001:1c03:2d05:7900:9d1c:c035:5b10:326]:55403/UDP(host(IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP)|candidate:4 1 UDP 2122187007 2001:1c03:2d05:7900:9d1c:c035:5b10:326 55403 typ host)
(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com):default)/CAND-PAIR(Yh2V): setting pair to state WAITING: Yh2V|IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP|IP6:[1111:1c03:2d05:7900:e5d6:372:496b:bbbb]:55402/UDP(host(IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP)|candidate:2 1 UDP 2122121471 1111:1c03:2d05:7900:e5d6:372:496b:bbbb 55402 typ host)
(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com):default)/CAND-PAIR(Yh2V): setting pair to state IN_PROGRESS: Yh2V|IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP|IP6:[1111:1c03:2d05:7900:e5d6:372:496b:bbbb]:55402/UDP(host(IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP)|candidate:2 1 UDP 2122121471 1111:1c03:2d05:7900:e5d6:372:496b:bbbb 55402 typ host)
(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com):default)/CAND-PAIR(3Smw): setting pair to state WAITING: 3Smw|IP4:192.168.178.13:60427/UDP|IP4:192.168.178.13:55404/UDP(host(IP4:192.168.178.13:60427/UDP)|candidate:6 1 UDP 2122055935 192.168.178.13 55404 typ host)
(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com):default)/CAND-PAIR(3Smw): setting pair to state IN_PROGRESS: 3Smw|IP4:192.168.178.13:60427/UDP|IP4:192.168.178.13:55404/UDP(host(IP4:192.168.178.13:60427/UDP)|candidate:6 1 UDP 2122055935 192.168.178.13 55404 typ host)
(generic/EMERG) Error in recvfrom: -5961
(ice/WARNING) ICE-PEER(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com):default): no pairs for 1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com) aLevel=0
(generic/EMERG) Error in recvfrom: -5961
(generic/EMERG) Error in recvfrom: -5961
(generic/EMERG) Error in recvfrom: -5961
(generic/EMERG) Error in recvfrom: -5961
(generic/EMERG) Error in recvfrom: -5961
(ice/INFO) ICE(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com)): peer (PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com):default) Trickle grace period is over; marking every component with only failed pairs as failed.
(generic/EMERG) Error in recvfrom: -5961
(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(dujC|IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP|IP6:[2222:1c03:2d05:7900:21e:33ff:fee1:cccc]:55401/UDP(host(IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP)|candidate:0 1 UDP 2122252543 2222:1c03:2d05:7900:21e:33ff:fee1:cccc 55401 typ host)): Timed out
(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com):default)/CAND-PAIR(dujC): setting pair to state FAILED: dujC|IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP|IP6:[2222:1c03:2d05:7900:21e:33ff:fee1:cccc]:55401/UDP(host(IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP)|candidate:0 1 UDP 2122252543 2222:1c03:2d05:7900:21e:33ff:fee1:cccc 55401 typ host)
(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(srflx(IP4:192.168.178.13:60427/UDP|stun3.l.google.com:19305)): Timed out
(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(P3yk|IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP|IP6:[2001:1c03:2d05:7900:9d1c:c035:5b10:326]:55403/UDP(host(IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP)|candidate:4 1 UDP 2122187007 2001:1c03:2d05:7900:9d1c:c035:5b10:326 55403 typ host)): Timed out
(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com):default)/CAND-PAIR(P3yk): setting pair to state FAILED: P3yk|IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP|IP6:[2001:1c03:2d05:7900:9d1c:c035:5b10:326]:55403/UDP(host(IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP)|candidate:4 1 UDP 2122187007 2001:1c03:2d05:7900:9d1c:c035:5b10:326 55403 typ host)
(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(Yh2V|IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP|IP6:[1111:1c03:2d05:7900:e5d6:372:496b:bbbb]:55402/UDP(host(IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP)|candidate:2 1 UDP 2122121471 1111:1c03:2d05:7900:e5d6:372:496b:bbbb 55402 typ host)): Timed out
(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com):default)/CAND-PAIR(Yh2V): setting pair to state FAILED: Yh2V|IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP|IP6:[1111:1c03:2d05:7900:e5d6:372:496b:bbbb]:55402/UDP(host(IP6:[9999:0:5ef5:79fd:3c24:1149:abe0:aaaa]:60428/UDP)|candidate:2 1 UDP 2122121471 1111:1c03:2d05:7900:e5d6:372:496b:bbbb 55402 typ host)
(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(3Smw|IP4:192.168.178.13:60427/UDP|IP4:192.168.178.13:55404/UDP(host(IP4:192.168.178.13:60427/UDP)|candidate:6 1 UDP 2122055935 192.168.178.13 55404 typ host)): Timed out
(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com):default)/CAND-PAIR(3Smw): setting pair to state FAILED: 3Smw|IP4:192.168.178.13:60427/UDP|IP4:192.168.178.13:55404/UDP(host(IP4:192.168.178.13:60427/UDP)|candidate:6 1 UDP 2122055935 192.168.178.13 55404 typ host)
(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com):default)/STREAM(1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com) aLevel=0)/COMP(1): All pairs are failed, and grace period has elapsed. Marking component as failed.
(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1461430033583000 (id=341 url=https://url.com):default): all checks completed success=0 fail=1
```

I have no clue what to do, it works fine on my own pc from browser to browser, on the internet from Chrome to Chrome, but as soon as Firefox comes into play outside localhost things break.

I'm using one stun server and no turn server. (I dont have my own atm)

Comment: There is a log error about missing STUN server. Have you tried using the google one? It's necessary for the peers to exchange their internet-facing network addresses.

Comment: That's actually a misleading error on Firefox's end. They are complaining about missing stun servers on the global setting although they are set on the connection level. I include one google stun server and it works all the time in chrome > chrome. Made a call from two countires within the EU just fine in chrome.